# Можно ли в Visual Studio указать текущий TargetFramework для проекта, у которого несколько TargetFrameworks?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Есть проект, который должен собираться под разные версии фреймворков. Вот csproj файл:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45;</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Some.HttpClient" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

И для такого проекта у меня подсвечивается синтаксис только для `.net standard 2.0`, в то время как для `net 4.5` он совсем не валидируется. Вот скриншот из Visual Studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как-то переключиться на `net45`, чтобы проверить ошибки компиляции в VisualStudio для сборки `net45`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто, но не так очевидно. Необходимый `target framework` можно выбрать на панели навигации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]